# Why IE10? Date creation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

This is output from IE10s console after my trying to convert a string to date.

```
>> new Date("1212-12-12T11:23:00.000+0000") 
Invalid Date 
Add to watch
```

Dose any one know if this is a bug or why it works like this in IE10? How can i get this to work?

In chrome and firefox I can simply call

```
>> new Date("1212-12-12T11:23:00.000+0000")
"Wed Dec 12 1212 12:23:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
```

Comment: Yes but im pretty sure I get the wrong date.

Comment: It seams formattedDate = new Date(date.split("+")[0]+"Z"); this might solve the problem.

Comment: Or use hh:mm for timezone: `"1212-12-12T11:23:00.000+00:00"`

Comment: If you're doing dates in the browser, I would strongly recommend using a library like Date.js or Moment.js. Dates are one of the areas where there are still some browser differences, particularly in how they handle parsing of date strings for input.